# Chrome app: Reading and writing data from/to a file on a server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome-app

I basically want to do an AJAX call to a PHP file on a server.  This doesn't seem to work using the XMLHttpRequest.
Lets say i have the following files:

A PHP file: http://abc.de.fg/folder/data.php

and a txt file: http://abc.de.fg/folder/data.txt

I want to, from my chrome app, pass some data to that PHP file and wait for the response.  The PHP file will read and write the data.txt file.

When I try to do this in a chrome app (I know this code works when run through a standard webpage) i get the following errors:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Content-length" main.js:250
(anonymous function) main.js:250

Refused to set unsafe header "Connection" main.js:251
(anonymous function) main.js:251

OPTIONS http://abc.de.fg/folder/data.php No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://ndakgilfeodmfkdmoojoeeckpajmflcd' is therefore not allowed access. main.js:253
(anonymous function) main.js:253

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://abc.de.fg/folder/data.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://ndakgilfeodmfkdmoojoeeckpajmflcd' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard of [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)? It's what prevents your client-side scripts from accessing information from a different domain. A different domain may be a totally different namespace, a subdomain, or even a different port.

The linked Wikipedia Article names the header that you'll need to send in your PHP generated response: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` which your browser already sais is lacking.

Depending on your situation, you're probably better off using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) since it does not require that header to be set. It's hard to set a proper allowed URI if it follows such an obscure pattern: chrome-extension://ndakgilfeodmfkdmoojoeeckpajmflcd

I'm not sure if that's an browser-generated UID created during installation, or if it's the UUID of your plugin as it is available in the Chrome App Store. I'm not a frequent Chrome App Developer...

Comment: I don't think JSONP will work due to the Content Security Policy used in Chrome apps. http://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy.html

Comment: @MatrixFrog That's an important addition. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be certain but I would check to make sure you have the right permissions in the manifest file (could you export a HAR from the network tab of the app for the request that fails?). You are allowed to make cross-domain requests in apps if you have declared that host in your permissions, see the first entry in the table on this page: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html

In short, the permission  "[scheme]:[host]/*" -

> Specifies a host permission. Required if the extension or app wants to interact with the code running on pages. Many capabilities, such as cross-origin XMLHttpRequests, programmatically injected content scripts, and the extension's cookies API require host permissions.

So you could have in your manifest file, for your above PHP example:

```
"permissions": [
    "http://abc.de.fg/*",
    ...
]
```